# Sorting in EF Core using OData to be case insensitive

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, odata

I'm using EF Core on my .NET Core 2.2 application to connect with DB, and Angular 8 on the front-end side. I'm also using OData to retrieve some data from my API.

**My OData query looks like this:**

```
https://example.com/Odata/Farmers?$count=true&$orderby=firstName%20asc&$top=10
```

The query above returns data sorted like:
`A, B, a, b`

but it **should** returns data like (case insensitive):
`A, a, B, b.`

**My .NET Core API endpoint looks like this:**

```
[EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False)]
[ODataRoute]
[AuthorizeScopes(AppScopes.FarmerListRead)]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<FarmerViewDto> GetAll()
{
    return _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>();
}
```

I found a property `EnableCaseInsensitive` in OData route configuration but it is for something else. I cannot find a proper solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```cs
public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<string> 
{ 
    public int Compare(string a, string b) 
    { 
        return string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
    } 
}

[EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False)]
[ODataRoute]
[AuthorizeScopes(AppScopes.FarmerListRead)]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<FarmerViewDto> GetAll()
{
    return _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>();
        .OrderBy(x => x.firstName, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
}
```

== Edit ==

The following Queryable extension supports sorting by a single column name in ascending or descending order (defaults to ascending)...

```cs
namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Sort<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, IComparer<string> comparer, string sortExpression)
        {
            bool sortDescending = false;
            if (sortExpression.EndsWith(" DESC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                sortDescending = true;
                sortExpression = sortExpression.Substring(0, sortExpression.Length - 5);
            }
            if (sortExpression.EndsWith(" ASC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                sortDescending = false;
                sortExpression = sortExpression.Substring(0, sortExpression.Length - 4);
            }

            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");
            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpression), typeof(string)), param);

            if (!sortDescending)
                return source.OrderBy<TSource, string>(expression, comparer);
            else
                return source.OrderByDescending<TSource, string>(expression, comparer);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could then use in the following way...

```cs
    return _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>();
        .Sort(new CaseInsensitiveComparer(), "firstName asc");
```

It assumes all object properties can be sensibly converted to string. If you have custom classes on your properties you'll need to ensure you override `ToString()` appropriately.

Also it only works for a single field, i.e.: `"field"`, `"field1 asc"` or `"field1 desc"`. I'll leave the extra silliness to you if you want something like `"field1 asc, field2 desc"`.

Comment: But the property I want to ordered by can be different each time, it comes from the front-end.

Comment: You could do that with reflection on `x`, but it would probably be horribly slow.

Comment: Yeah exactly :/ And I would like to have a pretty clean and universal solution for that.

Comment: Great answer! But it still needs from me to pass this argument from the OData query. Is it possible to pass to some EF Core configuration to always compare using case insensitive?

Comment: I don't believe there's a config setting that affects the default sort ordering - aside from changing the default Culture and UICulture settings to take international characters into account.

Comment: Also, I assumed the `&$orderby=firstName%20asc` in your URI query was the source, you should be able to retrieve that from your context. When not specified you could decorate your repo classes with a custom `[DefaultQueryableSort(fieldName,descending)]` attribute as a fallback. Also, where I've used `new CaseInsenstiveComparer()` you could also just use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` - the former is a good hook, though, if your string data needs to handle numeric sorting, i.e.: where `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` all need to appear before `10`, all of which need to appear before `A` and `a`.

Answer (score 1):

before you do the return

```
var farmerViewDto = _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>();


var returnValue = farmerViewDto.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.PropertyYouWantToSort, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).AsQueryable();

retur returnValue;
```

adding additional information on my comment 
faster yet a lot of code

```
var searchFilter = //user input

var query = _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>().AsQueryable();

if (searchFilter == "property1")
{
    query = query.OrdberBy(x => x.Property1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).AsQueryable();
}
if (searchFilter == "property2")
{
    query = query.OrdberBy(x => x.Property2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).AsQueryable();
}
.....

return query;
```

via reflection

```
var searchFilter = //user input

var query = _unitOfWork
        .FarmerViewRepository
        .GetAllQueryable()
        .UseAsDataSource()
        .For<FarmerViewDto>();

query.Where(x => x.GetType()
                  .GetProperty(searchFilter)
                  .GetValue(x).ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).AsQueryable();

return query;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP asked for case insensitive sorting. [StringComparer.Ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinal) is case sensitive, try [StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase) instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I misunderstood, editing answer, thanks for the heads up

Comment: But the property I want to ordered by can be different each time, it comes from the front-end, so I can't just hardcoded this property in backend

Comment: @XardasLord add the conditions you want it sorted by

Comment: @XardasLord then we create a query builder adding a different `OrderBy` for each condition

Comment: @GabLlorico Could you explain more? What do you mean by 'add the conditions'?

Comment: @XardasLord ill add it in my answer

Comment: @XardasLord added

Comment: Oh now I understand, thanks :) But is there any other way to do it more elegant and universal? I have many endpoints like that.

Comment: @XardasLord okay, added :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198025/discussion-between-gab-llorico-and-xardaslord).